# Is there a way to default your ssh user to something other than your currently logged in username?

Tags: ssh

I use a VM at home for work. My job consists of ssh'ing to several computers every day for various things... using the `ssh user@server`notation is easy enough for this, but I've run into some issues with some scripts I'm working on. When my scripts run, it's attempting to ssh to boxes using my current user instead of the user associated with my LDAP account at work (and thus, not recognizing my private key). More specifically, my user at home is `caleb`, whereas my user at work is `ctote`.

Is there a way to modify my `.bashrc` or `.ssh` configs to force ssh to always use `ctote` when trying to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use SSH client configuration. Easiest way is to create a local user configuration in `~/.ssh/config` with these two lines:

```
Host *
User ctote
```

This matches all hosts and applies the login name `ctote` to it.

To apply/override it for a single host you connect to ofen, use for example:

```
Host myhost
User myusername
Hostname server01.subdomain01.longnamehuh.tld
Port 2222
```

to make

```
ssh myusername@server01.subdomain01.longnamehuh.tld -p2222
```

into

```
ssh myhost
```

Bonus: also works for sftp/scp/git etc. And you can also do magic like this use case: [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/a/311454/88802).

Have a look at the manpage of SSH client configuration for more options you can specify and what the syntax is exactly.

```
man ssh_config
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can create a `~/.ssh/config` file and in that:

```
Host laptop
    User another-user
```

You can specify most SSH options through host-matched options like this.