# ssh port-forwarding through a server

Tags: ssh

In order to access to my pc at work i do:

```
ssh -AY myusername@server_of_the_company
```

and then:

```
ssh -AY myusername_at_my_pc@ip_address_of_my_pc
```

I read about ssh tunnelling but i cannot make it work. Which command should I use to connect directly from local to my pc at work?

Bonus question, how to setup scp to copy back and forth from local to my_pc?

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/q/311447/158095

Comment: @ARUL `scp` is very closely connected to `ssh`. Asking a different question for it is pointless.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Yes, that's a much better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
ssh -L 2222:ip_address_of_my_pc:22 -AY myusername@server_of_the_company
```

This will forward connections to port 2222 of localhost to port 22 of your PC.

Then, to connect to your PC, you can do (from your local system):

```
ssh -AY -p 2222 myusername_at_my_pc@localhost
```

`scp` works similarly.

Comment: from my local system to localhost? what do you mean?

Comment: `localhost` aka 127.0.0.1 is how you connect from your local system to itself. Since the forwarded port is on your local system, you connect to `localhost`.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. Or, more probably, I am misunderstanding. I would like to connect from my pc (localhost) to my pc at work (ip_address_of_my_pc). So in a terminal I use the first command and i and end up connected (as usual) to the server company. Then what? In another terminal I should connect to myself?

Comment: @thunder1123 yes.

Comment: and how to make the first step permanent?

Comment: @thunder1123 there's no way to make it *permanent*. You will need  to start a connection to `server_of_the_company` some way or the other. At best, you can add a `Host` entry to [`~/.ssh/config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) and specify `LocalForward` there.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host my_pc
  ProxyCommand ssh -a server_of_the_company -W %h:%p
```