# Connect to server through intermedieate computer

Tags: networking, ssh, login

I have accounts on 2 other machines machine 1: 172.16.68.1 and machine 2: 172.16.68.3 i use ssh to  login to machine 1.

I am unable to directly ssh to machine to but once i have logged in in machine 1, i am able to login using ssh to machine 2.

Is there a way i can directly ssh to machine 2?

Or at least i need a way to use the connect to server option to login to machine 2, because the login to machine 1 then login to machine 2 works via the terminal, but it won't work via the connect to server option.
I need a gui way to browse machine 2, open files via sublime in my current machine etc.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT :**

I tried the solution given in [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command)

It works for me in the terminal, but the gui connect to server fails saying

**Unhandled error message: Timed out when logging in**

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Notice the Connect to server in the left panel, that's what i am talking about.

Comment: What is the "gui connect to server" you're talking about?  Do you need that if the command line is working?

Comment: well, it's just that if i use the gui, i can use my text editors to open the files in the remote machine. I have included a screenshot of the gui!

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
ssh 172.16.68.3 -l your_username_on_machine_2
```

Make sure the ssh service is started during system start, not after login:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

For a GUI way to login to a second computer enable desktop sharing on the required machine and use [remmina](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/remmina/) to connect via remote desktop.

Be sure you enable the required ports on firewall.