# SSH over SSH without confirmation

Tags: networking, ssh

I need to use SSH over SSH without confirmation in two hosts or at lease without confirmation on the second host.

Expected behavior:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineB ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineA
```

Currently working only:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineB ssh user@machineA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command)

Comment: Hello! What actually you want to achieve? Probably creating ssh tunnel will be more elegant solution. Please check this topic: [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005337/566421). A secure way to log-in into a ssh server without conformation is to use ssh *key based authentication* and a key with empty *passphrase*.

Comment: As I read the question again, I think the duplicate does not really fit. Is the Host key always changing on your server? Otherwise, you have to confirm only once, or put the key manually to the known_hosts file, then you don't need to confirm anything. I would not turn off that security feature.

Comment: this is my solution:

     ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A "ssh-keyscan 10.10.x2.x &>/dev/null && ssh -q -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'10.10.x2.x ls -la"

by ssh-keyscan I can reach another host without confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes for everything after the first `ssh` command:

```bash
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineB "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineA"
```

I'm not sure as to your purpose with the `-t` flag, it is not mentioned in the docs. If you need it for the first `ssh` command, then you probably need it for the second `ssh` as well, so, if the above doesn't work, try either of these:

**Both `-t`** :

```bash
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineB "ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineA"
```

**Neither `-t`** :

```bash
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineB "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user@machineA"
```