# Meaning of SSH command with 2 IPs

Tags: command-line, networking, ssh

Often I have seen ssh commands like:

```
ssh user1@user2@<one-ip-address>@<second-ip-address
```

First I thought this is to ssh through another server. But several questions and examples like [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command) gives better solutions for server through ssh.

So, my question is what kind of scenarios we have to use the above kind of ssh commands. What is the destination of the ssh command?

Comment: "Often"? Can you show as an example somewhere? Because as far as `ssh` is concerned, everything before the last `@` is just the username.

Comment: @muru maybe using "often" is not valid in globally. But I have seen this in lots of scenarios in my working place. But I could not found the proper reson.

Comment: @VikumDheemantha and you're **certain** it was `user1@user2@ip1@ip2`? Not `user1@domain1@ip2`?

Comment: i have never seen that.

Comment: @muru yes. There are 2 users, entire command contain 3 '@' symbols.

Comment: Then your company configuration is probably parsing the username at the server for some reason. That's something only your company can tell you why.

Comment: @muru so what you mean is that there is no common scenario that uses SSH like this.

Comment: I know of `user@domain@hostname`, which is for AD domain users, but I don't think I have ever seen `user1@ip1@user2@ip2`.

Comment: @muru actually it is not `user1@ip1@user2@ip2` as you mentioned in the comment. it is `user1@user2@ip1@ip2` even in `user@domain@hostname` structure IP addresses are useless, as I think.

Comment: Never seen that either. `hostname` could be IP in `user@domain@hostname`, hence the relevance.

Comment: @VikumDheemantha You said you have often seen this command. Since none of us have ever seen this can you post the link or reference where this exact command was used.

Comment: There being "better solutions" doesn't mean that SSH can't do something else: I think you might be talking about ProxyJump (see eg [Section 6 on ProxyJump here](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/advanced-ssh-6-things/)), which is mentioned on the [page you link](https://askubuntu.com/a/996657/29073) ?

Comment: @pbhj it seams proxy jump is the answer. So, can you add here it as an answer? So I can spend my bounty properly.

Comment: You insisted that the entire command contained 3 `@`s. What was the actual command then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an SSH feature called **ProxyJump**:

`ssh -J user1@proxy.server1.tld:port1,user2@proxy.server2.tld:port2 user@yourserver.tld`

which sounds like what you're referring to.

More information on this in eg [Section 6 on ProxyJump here](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/advanced-ssh-6-things/) or this [page on ProxyJump from RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump). In particular note that there are alternative formats, eg when the user:passwd are the same on each host (don't do that!). You can also put the info into a config file to avoid typing it out each time (though `history` is useful there).

Finally there are other ways to achieve the same thing, in SSH: `-o proxycommand=`, and `-q -W` (the later explained here on [ExplainShell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-q+-W+%25h%3A%25p+myserver)).

Answer (score 3):

As many of the comments suggest, the syntax `ssh user1@user2@<one-ip-address>@<second-ip-address` does not lead to a useful ssh behavior and it has nothing to do with the jump host function.

Try the following:

- On any system, connect with your current user to localhost:

  ```
  $ ssh localuser@localhost
  ```

  This will, as expected, open a `ssh` session on localhost
- Now try the same with the proposed syntax:

  ```
  $ ssh localuser@localhost@localuser@localhost
  localuser@localhost@localuser@localhost's password: 
  Permission denied, please try again.
  ...
  ```

  You will be asked for a password, but the system will not let you in, since the user
  `localuser@localhost@localuser` does not exist on the system.

  Also check the output of `/var/log/auth.log`:

  ```
  Aug 17 08:45:46 somehost sshd[73042]: Invalid user localuser@localhost@localuser from 127.0.0.1 port 44292
  Aug 17 08:45:48 somehost sshd[73042]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
  Aug 17 08:45:48 somehost sshd[73042]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=127.0.0.1 
  Aug 17 08:45:50 somehost sshd[73042]: Failed password for invalid user localuser@localhost@localuser from 127.0.0.1 port 44292 ssh2
  ```

Unless you create a user `localuser@localhost@localuser` on the system you want to connect to, this syntax won't work.

Comment: Indeed; I have verified this as well. I have a situation where I'm using this exact syntax _without_ the `-J` (ProxyJump) flag and it appears that everything preceding that last `@` is indeed simply treated as a username, even if there are other multiple `@` and may actually be an internal mechanism behind the scenes that works similar to proxy/bastion. This has proven useful for configuring `.ssh/config` to shorten the command.