# How to connect to a server via 2 Jump host servers ? (For SSH and File transferring)

Tags: 20.04, ssh, files, remote-access, tools

I currently use *[Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)* on top of [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) for this task. But Mobaxterm runs very slowly in my Ubuntu 20.4 VM and most of the time, it gets stuck. Is there any other easy solution for SSH and File transferring to a server via 2 jump hosts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, normal `ssh` client / `scp` can do that. And there has been many questions+answers how to achieve that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command). This can be easily chained.